# Meteor won't load client libraries

Tags: meteor, libraries, typeerror

I'm trying to use chartjs by DevExpress in a meteor project and I am unable to load the required client libraries. In my project directory I have a 'client' folder with two items; dx.chartjs and globalize.min

I recieve two errors when the loading the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DevExpress' of undefined
```

and

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dxPieChart'
    at Object.Template.hello.rendered (http://localhost:3000/chart.js?15ecf0e00ba2737900c70309ae9e83a5e6402b17:15:22)
    at Spark.createLandmark.rendered (http://localhost:3000/packages/templating.js?3e5f495522f23490e6711696b729358477f2105b:181:42)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?89d98339d0de8299aab5a40fa82010709f0606ee:443:32
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?ab3604ad6a217062906fb40c8236bb7e59f51a7f:130:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?89d98339d0de8299aab5a40fa82010709f0606ee:441:7
    at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?3ca61f7bda24db4f00839466f22fd1d61de37661:265:11)
```

my code is incredibly simple
HTML file

```
<head>
  <title>chart</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <div id="chartContainer"/>
</template>
```

and the js file

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.hello.rendered = function() {
    var dataSource = [
    { country: "Russia", area: 12 },
    { country: "Canada", area: 7 },
    { country: "USA", area: 7 },
    { country: "China", area: 7 },
    { country: "Brazil", area: 6 },
    { country: "Australia", area: 5 },
    { country: "India", area: 2 },
    { country: "Others", area: 55 }
];

$("#chartContainer").dxPieChart({
    size:{ 
        width: 500
    },
    dataSource: dataSource,
    series: [
        {
            argumentField: "country",
            valueField: "area",
            label:{
                visible: true,
                connector:{
                    visible:true,           
                    width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    title: "Area of Countries"
});
  }

}
```

I have yet to replicate this problem using another machine. I have uninstalled and re-installed multiple times with no luck. Has anybody encountered or can shed light on why this error might be occurring?

Comment: Where does DevExpress appear in your code?

Comment: Have you tried it using the atmosphere library instead of putting the 3rd party code directly into your app? `mrt add chartjs`

Comment: @Cuberto, that is another library, not what author is trying to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the files in client/compatibility directory. From the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

> Some JavaScript libraries only work when placed in the
>   client/compatibility subdirectory.